# How can i update my app

Tags: android, version, android-5.0-lollipop, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-6.0.1-marshmallow

I have buyed a Android app but Author not respons more.
App was created to this versions:
Android 4.0, Android 4.0.3, Android 4.0.4, Android 4.1.x, Android 4.2.x, Android 4.3.x, Android 4.4.x

Now we also have 5x and 6x so my questions are:
How can i do it so it works with newest version to Android?
I have full source code for this app.

Comment: It should work without any changes

Answer (score 0):

Change your `build.gradle` file configuration to the Android API level you're looking for.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.your.package"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
}
```

API:

- 19 - 4.4 - 4.4.x
- 21 - 5.0 22 - 5.1
- 23 - 6.0 - 6.0.1
- 24 - (Android Nougat)

[Source](https://source.android.com/source/build-numbers.html)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to update the build.gradle to target newer versions (although the app may run fine on newer versions without it).

Moreover, you should be updating your code to explicitly request permissions for Marshmallow and Nougat, as outlined [here](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html).

Answer (score 0):

Configure your build.gradle, and update targetSdkVersion to android version which you wanted.